# GDB: disable printing of current line after every step

Tags: gdb

The GNU gdb commandline debugger prints the line it is currently on after every `step` and `next` command. Consider the following gdb session where I step through some code:

```
...
Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd848)
    at src/main.cc:3
3       int main(int argc, char **argv){
(gdb) next
4           Printf("Hello World\n");    // <--- disable this
(gdb) 
5           printf("Hello World 2\n");  // <--- disable this
(gdb)
```

Is there a gdb setting to disable this printing? I know this is technically possible because the gdb TUI has exactly the behaviour i'm looking for (accessible through gdb command `set enable tui`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I achieved it through redirection:

```
define n
    set logging file /dev/null
    set logging redirect on
    set logging enabled on
    next
    set logging enabled off
    display
end
```

I found that capturing the output of `next` did not work using `gdb.execute` (gdb's python API). I expect that this is the case because the source line is not printed by `next` itself, but by the stop event that is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to do this when using the gdb CLI.  The code that handles printing the "stop" to the user does not check anything that the user can set.

One way you could try solving this would be to alias `n` to a command that runs the command using a different interpreter, like `interpreter-exec tui next`.  I am not sure if this will actually work.

Another way to accomplish this would be to write a Python command named `n` that uses `gdb.execute` to invoke `next` -- while capturing the output and ignoring it.  This approach is somewhat dangerous because sometimes you probably do want some of the stop message, just not the source display.

The best approach would be to modify gdb to add a new `set` command to disable the source printing.  This is easy to do.

Comment: I've noticed that [cgdb](https://cgdb.github.io/) is able to achieve this while using an unaltered gdb. Any clue on how they did it?

Comment: cgdb is a wrapper so it can filter the output any way it likes.  So presumably that's what it does - but I'm just guessing, I have never looked at the cgdb sources.

Comment: the printing source location is "disabled" when executing `interpreter-exec console next`. Unfortunately, when putting this command in a function (`define n \n interpreter-exec console next \n end`) gdb generates a segfault. Any ideas?