# gdb - disable printing of return value when calling `finish`

Tags: gdb

simply put - any way to completely disable printing after calling `finish`?

I tried modifying [the accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295269/gdb-disable-printing-of-current-line-after-every-step) but the result is not satisfying because:

1. if the returned value is too big you still get the annoying `"---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---"`
2. it still takes a while to run as if the output if being printed - very impactful when the returned object is big

think about something like wanting to step into `simple_computation()` and this is the actual line `int res = get_huge_singleton_manager().simple_computation();`

yes, we could write it as 2 lines of code:

```
auto&& m = get_huge_singleton_manager();
int res = m.simple_computation();
```

and there wouldn't be an issue but we don't always have control of the code we're debugging...

Comment: @MarkPlotnick actually it does work. it doesn't achieve the (2) issue but I guess it's something. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting in GDB 9, there is a command to disable this printing:

```
(gdb) set print finish off
```

This is documented [in the manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping).